# How do i get my id out through my repository?

Tags: java, android, repository, android-room

I have a room database running in the background on a `AsyncTask` that when called it inserts the certain class that I have as a entity. The request in my `CustomerDao` can return a long as an id.

The thing is though that I'm using a repository to save my class into the room database and for that I need a AsyncTask and some void to be able to reach my insert function.

My question now though is how do I get this long out to my `MainViewController` via the repository and the `AsyncTask`? I am not able to request a long from a new InsertAsync task? so how do I then return my id all the way to the `MainActivity`?

Tell me what code you need I'm happy to help though right now I will send you my Main and my Repository.

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.jenso.paperseller;

import android.arch.lifecycle.Observer;
import android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.support.v7.widget.helper.ItemTouchHelper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    FloatingActionButton fab;
    private CustomerViewModel mCustomerViewModel;
    public static final int NEW_CUSTOMER_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private static final  String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler);

        final PapperRecyclerAdapter adapter = new PapperRecyclerAdapter(this);

        fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);

        mCustomerViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(CustomerViewModel.class);

        new ItemTouchHelper(new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0,ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT ) {
            @Override
            public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
            }
        }).attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);

        mCustomerViewModel.getmAllCustomers().observe(this, new Observer<List<Customer>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable List<Customer> customers) {
                adapter.setCustomer(customers);
            }
        });

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CreateCustomer.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, NEW_CUSTOMER_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        });
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    }

    public void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == NEW_CUSTOMER_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String[] mCustomerSave = data.getStringArrayExtra(CreateCustomer.EXTRA_REPLY);
            Customer customer = new Customer(mCustomerSave[0],mCustomerSave[1],mCustomerSave[2],mCustomerSave[3]);
            Long id  = mCustomerViewModel.insert(customer);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    R.string.empty_not_saved,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
package com.example.jenso.paperseller;

import android.app.Application;
import android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

import java.util.List;

public class CustomerRepository {
    private CustomerDao mCustomerDao;
    private LiveData<List<Customer>> mAllCustomers;

    public CustomerRepository(Application application) {
            CustomerDatabase db = CustomerDatabase.getDatabase(application);

            mAllCustomers = mCustomerDao.getAllCustomers();
            mCustomerDao = db.customerDao();
    }

    LiveData<List<Customer>> getAllCustomers(){
        return mAllCustomers;
    }
    //public void deleteOneCustomer(int id){new insertAsyncTask(mCustomerDao).}

    public void insert (Customer customer){
        new insertAsyncTask(mCustomerDao).execute(customer);
    }

    public void delete(Customer customer) {
        new insertAsyncTask(mCustomerDao).execute(customer);
    }

    private static class insertAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Customer, Void, Void> {
        private CustomerDao mAsyncTaskDao;

        insertAsyncTask(CustomerDao dao) {
            mAsyncTaskDao = dao;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(final Customer... params) {
            mAsyncTaskDao.insertAll(params[0]);

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you use `Void, Void`? [https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: I don't know how to reformat the AsyncTask to send out a Long but I will take a look at your link eaven if I think I alredy did...:D

Comment: that's exactly what the example does in this link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all use a single `ASyncTask` to handle both delete and insert (and probably more in future) is wrong. You should know that `AsyncTask` is just a worker and since you using `Repository` pattern it should not contain any logic. You should create a task that return long:

```
 private static class DeleteTask extends AsyncTask<Customer, Void, Long> {
        private CustomerDao dao;

        DeleteTask (CustomerDao dao) {
            this.dao = dao;
        }

        @Override
        protected Long doInBackground(final Customer... params) {
            return dao.delete(params[0]);;
        }
    }
```

Second of all since you use repository pattern you can just format the response needed inside the repository itself:

```
public long delete(Customer customer) {
        new insertAsyncTask(mCustomerDao).execute(customer);
        return customer.id; //Return Primary key
    }
```

Comment: I am using it the thing is that here I'm not in my repository... I'm using this tutorial and this is how my code looks like... https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex the thing is that I want to get the id to delete the customer

Comment: Ah but how will I call the deleteTask without a id

Comment: No Id is needed, room can infer the the object you trying to delete using the primary key you set (using @PrimaryKey annotation in your model class)

Comment: Yea but the primary key in my Class is the id

Comment: So? isn't the primary key which room use to delete object is already available inside Customer object? if not then your entire code logic is wrong here..

Comment: atleast as I understood room the  @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) id concatenates the key with the id?

Comment: no, it generate the id itself. if you trying to delete an object previously retrieved from database it already contains the primary key. if not you must query data base to delete an object based on a key you want.

Comment: But I mean it must be the Id then that I should try to get from the customer I have... or am I wrong though I mean if I have downloaded a pile of customers then shouldn't I get an key to delete the data with by calling the get id function on one of those items?

Comment: No, you can't delete something that may or may not be inside your database, if you downloaded customer you must either save them first or you must query delete customer based on a unique fields like social number.

Comment: so I must save a customer in like a private Customer spot then go through the list of customers I get with the help of the position in my recyclerview and send in the customer I whant to delete that way?

Comment: Yes, if you have a repository you must implement proper cache method, so the data in view is always synced with the data in database

Comment: So I can't save the data in a List<Customer> that is private in the class main and go from there?

Comment: can I ask for the code that comes with this cache method of yours?

Comment: It is a simple chain call in repository, for example:

    public Observable<List<Customer>> getCustomers() {
        return remoteDataStore.getCustomers()
                .doOnNext(new Consumer<List<Customer>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(List<Customer> customers) throws Exception {
                        localDataStore.insertAllCustomers(customers);
                    }
                });
    }